# Identity server authentication on api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 projects.
Test client mvc, and web-api.
I want do authentication on api.

Client:

```
public async Task < ActionResult > CallBackend() {

    var client = HttpClientHelper.GetClient(null, User.Identity);

    //api call is not succes. 
    //Variable egsResponse have value : {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', 
    //Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:... –
    HttpResponseMessage egsResponse = await client.GetAsync("api/secured");

    IEnumerable < Claim > result = null;
    if (egsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        string egsContent = await egsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < IEnumerable < Claim >> (egsContent);
    }

    return View(result);
}
```

api:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Get() {
    var identity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

    IEnumerable < Claim > claims = null;
    claims = User.Claims;
    return Ok(new ObjectResult(claims));
}
```

startup of api:

```
      public class Startup {
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {}
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        var factory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService < ILoggerFactory > ();
        factory.AddConsole();

        //error is probably here !!!!!!!
        //something missing to make identoty server visible for api project. 
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:54540/";
            options.Audience = "myClient";
        });
        app.UseMvc();

    }
}
```

I get error:

> System.InvalidOperationException The following authentication scheme
> was not accepted:
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.d__10.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionResults.ChallengeResult.d__14.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Actions.FilterActionInvoker.d__53.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Actions.FilterActionInvoker.d__41.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Actions.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.d__10.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- exception rethrown ---   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__18.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.d__13.MoveNext()
>
> --- exception rethrown ---   at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.d__13.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.d__9.MoveNext()

Comment: Have you investigated fixing this error? What have you tried, what were the problems?

Comment: In CallBackend method, api call is not succes. Variable egsResponse have value : {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:...

Comment: I think that error is in Configure Startup. Something missing to make identity server visible for api project.